# If A is infinite, does there have to exist a subset of A that is equivalent to A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading Rudin and there is an alternative definition of infinite set (the first definition is "not finite"): A is infinite if it is equivalent to one of its subset. Then I was wondering the converse: if A is infinite, does there have to exist a subset of A that is equivalent to A?

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: @GnuEmacs Presumably, "equinumerous."

Comment: @GnuEmacs this is exactly where I got a little unsure when I read this as well! This is what Rudin says...I'm not quite sure what equivalent means here so I don't know how to show such proper subset exist...

Comment: @S.W.Cheung The answer is more subtle than that - it depends on whether we assume the axiom of choice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: @User2313 That's not really relevant here - the problem is that, without the axiom of choice, there may be an infinite set $A$ with no nontrivial self-injection from $A$ to $A$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think its a good stepping stone to understand this problem.

Comment: I am sure that the definition included equivalent to one of its **proper** subsets.  Let A be the set of US states when Clinton was president.  Let B be the set of US states when Bush was president.  They are both subsets of the other so both are infinite.

Comment: Some related older posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250092/a-set-is-infinite-iff-it-is-equivalent-to-a-proper-subset-of-itself,
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524029/a-set-is-infinite-iff-there-is-a-one-to-one-correspondent-with-one-of-its-proper

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Great question! It turns out the answer is: sort of! It depends on exactly what **axioms** for set theory we use - specifically, whether or not we accept (an extremely weak form of) the **axiom of choice**.

In ZF alone - that is, set theory without any form of the axiom of choice - it is consistent that there are infinite sets which are strictly larger than all of their proper subsets ("infinite, Dedekind finite sets"). It is even possible to have sets which are infinite, but cannot be partitioned into *two* infinite pieces ("amorphous sets")!

---

Here's a proof that every infinite set has a proper subset of the same size. Let $A$ be infinite. Since $A$ is infinite, we know $A$ has at least $n$ elements, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (the proof is a very silly induction argument :P).

Now let $X_n$ be the set of all length-$n$ sequences of distinct elements of $A$. So, for instance, $X_1=\{\langle a\rangle: a\in A\}$. Note that each element of $X_n$ comes equipped with an *ordering* (this was missing in my original write-up, but it's crucially important). $X_n\not=\emptyset$ for each $n$, so - and here we use the axiom of choice - we may pick a family of representatives, $x_n\in X_n$. Then $B=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n$ is a subset of $A$ equinumerous with the natural numbers! (This is a good exercise.)

Now we're done: it's easy to see that the natural numbers are equinumerous with e.g. the even numbers, so $B$ is equinumerous with a proper subset $B'\subset B$; so $A=B\cup (A\setminus B)$ is equinumerous with $B'\cup (A\setminus B)$, which is a proper subset of $A$.

---

The proof that we **need** the axiom of choice here is extremely hard, and requires a powerful set-theoretic technique called **forcing**.

Comment: Very interesting! What does ZF stand for? What is an example of an infinite set that cannot be partitioned into two infinite pieces?

Comment: @ShiyueLi "ZF" just stands for "Zermelo-Fraenkel," the names of the two mathematicians who introduced it. Sadly, there isn't a good example of such an infinite set - after all, it's consistent that there *isn't* such a set at all! Indeed, showing that such sets are possible is **extremely** hard.

Comment: The proof you refer to needs *more* than forcing. It needs more techniques, either inner models (relative constructibility or relative definability) or symmetric extensions (which in itself is an extension of forcing). And I wouldn't say it's **extremely** hard. It's definitely not easy, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was including "symmetric submodels" as a subtopic of "forcing," but maybe that was gauche of me. :) As for difficulty, I think it does qualify as extremely hard - at least, from the point of view of the amount of effort needed to master it, starting from just beginning set theory (i.e., unfamiliarity with ZF).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you first for so much insight! Then I was looking at the part where you said B is an equinumerous subset of A. Does equinumerous just mean the same cardinality?

Comment: @ShiyueLi Yup, "equinumerous" just means "has the same cardinality as" - which in turn means that there is a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: @ShiyueLi There are a lot of terms used to denote the concept "has the same cardinality" like equinumerous, equipollent, equipotent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : $\:$ That is definitely _not_ "a good exercise", [since it's not provable in ZF](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119630/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_47-2006-4_15.pdf). $\hspace{1 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer You're absolutely right! I got caught on a very silly-seeming but important point - they should be finite **sequences** of elements, not **sets**. I've fixed it.

Comment: I have several questions about your proof. Why are you saying that the proper subset $B'$ has the same cardinality as $B$ and why $B′∪(A∖B)$ has the same cardinality as $A$? How are you getting that $B$ has the same cardinality as $N$?

Comment: Re: your first question, assume for a second that we know that $B$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$ (I'll explain how we know this later on). Fix some bijection $f:B\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$; if $U$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which is in bijection with all of $\mathbb{N}$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a proper subset of $B$ which is in bijection with all of $B$. The set $B'$ is just such a set - say, $f^{-1}(\{$even numbers$\})$.

Comment: Finally, re: your first question, fix some bijection $g:B'\rightarrow B$ and consider the function $$h:B'\cup(A\setminus B)\rightarrow B\cup(A\setminus B)$$ given by $h(c)=g(c)$ if $c\in B'$ and $h(c)=c$ if $c\in A\setminus B$. This $h$ is well-defined (since there is nothing in both $B'$ and $A\setminus B$, there's no ambiguity in the definition of $h$) and is a bijection.

Comment: @user13 Re: your last question, we need to be careful: without choice, the union of countably many finite sets need not be countable. This is why we worked with the $X_n$s above: the set $B$ we're building comes with an explicit ordering! Namely, look at the sequence $y$ gotten by concatenating the $x_i$s in order (that is, $x_1x_2x_3...$) and then removing repetitions (so if $x_1=\langle 3\rangle$, $x_2=\langle 4,1\rangle$, and $x_3=\langle 5, 1, 3\rangle$, the sequence $y$ would begin $3,4,1,5$; the second $1$ and second $5$ would both be removed since they're repetitions of earlier terms).

Comment: Now let's think about the length of $y$. Since each $x_i$ involves $i$ distinct elements, we know $y$ is infinite even though we may have removed lots of repetitions.This means that the map sending the $m$th term of $y$ to the natural number $m$ is **surjective** - since we've removed all repetitions, this in fact gives a bijection between the set of terms of $y$ (that is, $B$) and $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Since this comment thread is already a bit long, I'd suggest asking further questions as new math.stackexchange questions.

Comment: I doubt that the proof is quite correct. What guarantees that the chosen $x_n$’s are not all the constant sequences?

Comment: Also how do you define “union” on sequences?(Apologies for so many comments on such a old question, but I thought it’s worth clarifying)

Comment: [I edited the post regarding Atom's comment, since the  author of this post   seems inactive, its still not clear what unioning the sequences means, untill you scroll down and look at the comments, I suppose when the author is active again, they can *clarify in the post*] [I will note that all of this is happening because the author does not want to use "countable union of countable sets is countable" in order to make the argument simpler]

Comment: Also i dont understand how B is the same as *y* which is  formed by concatenating the $x_{i}$ in order and removing repetitions, i think its different and this should be clarified, perhaps you meant bijection between the *terms* of B and $\mathbb{N}?$

Comment: Oh! Now i think i get it the cardianlity of B is that of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$  right?...(By your argument that y is countable;I hope thats correct) . Can someone please clarify this problem has been driving me mad for days!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Assuming the axiom of choice, if $A$ is infinite then $A$ contains a countably infinite subset $S=\{s_1,s_2,...\}$. Construct a bijection $f:A\to A-\{s_1\}$ by $f(s_i)=s_{i+1}$ for $s_i\in S$ and $f(a)=a$ if $a\notin S$.

Comment: I strongly recommend Raymond Wilder's _Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics_ for anyone interested in this sort of topic, it's a wonderful book dealing with this kind of question and more!

Comment: Does "infinite" include the case of "uncountably infinite"? If so then does this proof still work?

Comment: Yes it still works since every uncountably infinite sets contain countably infinite subset (if we assume axiom of choice, Mr.Noah has covered the topic a lot more thoroughly than I). Think about the real line, for example. Let $f$ sends $n$ to $n+1$ when $n\in \{0,1,2,...\}$ and fixed every other points. $f$ is then a bijection $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R-\{0\}$.

Comment: Is the axiom of choice really needed for the first step? Why?

Comment: @alexis Well, think about how you prove that an infinite set has a countably infinite subset: you pick an $x_0$, then you pick an $x_1$, then . . . Any proof you write down will require (some version of) the axiom of choice. Of course, it's a huge step to go from that to "there **is no** proof without using the axiom of choice," but we can prove that, too - it's just very hard.

Comment: @alexis I'm sorry, I only know that AoC implies the first step but showing that it's really needed is beyond my current ability. I believe you should consult Mr. Noah or Mr. Asaf for that kind of information.

Comment: @alexis : Some (sufficiently strong) choice axiom is needed in the first step because the first step requires an infinite sequence of choices from an infinite sequence of distinct sets.  The set from which the second choice is made isn't even specifiable until the first choice is made.  And likewise for all the subsequent sets.  The axiom of dependent choice is strong enough.  (Let X be the given set.  Work in the collection of finite and countably infinite subset of X.  Relate by inclusion.  Apply dependent choice.  With a little fussing, this gives an infinite sequence in X.)

Comment: In words: every infinite set includes a Hilbert hotel. By taking out the first room, the resulting set is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, everyone. My curiosity is satisfied by the role of the AoC in the "obvious" construction. So Rudin's "is not finite" means "there is no bijection to an element of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @alexis Yes, that is what "infinite" (or "not finite") means.