# Number of rational numbers $\in (0,1) = $ number of rational numbers $\in (\frac{1}{2}$, 1)?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, rational-numbers, paradoxes

Let's say we have a set S of all rational number $\in (0,1)$. Now let us transform S to get a new set $S^{'}$ with the condition $x \in S \implies x + 1 \in S^{'}$. Now we again transform the set $S^{'}$ to get a new set $S^{"}$ with the condition $x \in S^{'} \implies \frac{1}{x} \in S^{"}$. Now number of elements in $S, S^{'} \;\&\; S^{"}$ is equal and all elements are rational. Also $x \in S$ satisfies $0 < x < 1 \;\&\; x \in S^{"}$ satisfies $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$. So we have number of rational numbers $\in (0,1) = $ number of rational numbers $\in (\frac{1}{2}$, 1)? (which is clearly incorrect).

Even simpler, we can transform S to get a new set $S^{'''}$ with the condition $x \in S \implies \frac{x+1}{2} \in S^{'''}$. Again, all elements in $S \;\&\; S^{'''}$ are rational and number of elements in both sets is equal. Also $x \in S$ satisfies $0 < x < 1 \;\&\; x \in S^{'''}$ satisfies $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$. So we have number of rational numbers $\in (0,1) = $ number of rational numbers $\in (\frac{1}{2}$, 1)? (which is clearly incorrect).

My question is : what is the flaw in both cases? I thought for a long time but I don't think I can find any problem in any of the methods.

P.S. : I am sorry if this was posted earlier somewhere on the site, I tried searching for it but could not find it.

Comment: There is no flaw. $(0, 1)$ and $(1/2, 1)$ have the same cardinality (which is the cardinality of $\Bbb R$) – compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/783020/42969.

Comment: Why is it clearly incorrect? Both sets have $\aleph_0$ elements, equal size. When it comes to infinity, we have to put intuition aside. An infinite set can have the same cardinality as a proper subset.

Comment: But $(0,1)$ includes the rational numbers in $(\frac{1}{2},1)$ and also includes rational numbers in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ (positive number of elements) so how can both sets have the same number of rational numbers?

Comment: A simpler “paradox”: The set of all even integers has the same cardinality as the set of all integers.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1672190/42969: *Every infinite set* has a strict subset with the same cardinality.

Comment: @HamLemon On the other hand, many other people would claim the sets should have equal size, as they are both infinite. This is why we have to work with precise definitions. Two sets have the same cardinality (by definition) if there is a bijection between the two sets. (and if you think of it, this definition makes sense. To this day no one came with a better idea to define cardinality) This leads to different non intuitive results: $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ have the same cardinality, while $\mathbb{R}$ is larger than both.

Comment: A less convoluted example: For each rational $x \in (0,1)$ take $\tfrac{x}{2} \in (0,\tfrac{1}{2})$, so $(0,1)$ and $(0,\tfrac{1}{2})$ have the same number of rationals.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. This greatly improved my understanding of sets and dealing with infinite terms and also showed my lack of understanding. I will try to be more knowledgeable next time I post a question like this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So from all the answers I have gotten, and my own thinking about this question I have a kind of an explanation for this result which goes as follows :

Let us take the transformation from $S \to S''$

Let us take a rational number x and let us say the immediate next rational number of x is x+y. While converting to $S''$ we added 1 to both numbers and took their reciprocals so the new rational numbers ($\in [1/2,1]$) are $\frac{1}{x+1} \;\&\; \frac{1}{x+y+1}$. Let us find the difference between these two numbers.

It comes out to be $\frac{y}{(x+1) \cdot (x+y+1)}$ and since both $(x+1),(x+y+1) > 1$ we get $\frac{y}{(x+1) \cdot (x+y+1)} < y$

Thus we essentially squeezed two rational numbers $\in [0,1]$ into the interval $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ by reducing the "distance" between them.

Same can be done in the transformation of $S \to S'''$ where by dividing by 2 we reduced the "distance" between any two rational numbers by 2 and squeezed them into an interval length half of their original interval length.

This is also the case with the common example of lines and number of points (drawing 2 parallel lines of different lengths and when their ends are connected by 2 different lines, both visually have a different length but algebraically the same number of points : [diagram for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0EkN.png)). When we are saying every point on line AR has a corresponding point on BR, we can see that what we have essentially done is reduced the distance between two successive points in BR and "squeezed" them into AR (if the distance between successive points in BR is x and angle between lines AR and BR is $\theta$ then distance between corresponding points in AR is $x \sin\theta$ and since $\sin \theta < 1$ the distance between corresponding successive points in AR is lesser than that in BR) (or increased the distance between two successive points in AR and fit them in BR (if the distance between successive points in AR is x and angle between lines AR and BR is $\theta$ then distance between corresponding points in AR is $\frac{x}{\sin\theta}$ and since $\sin \theta < 1$ the distance between corresponding successive points in BR is greater than that in AR)).

Thus we can conclude that any algebraic/geometric manipulation to make number of elements (infinite) in one set equal to that in another set of intuitively larger (or smaller) length, we unintentially/intentionally squeeze (or eleongate) the "distances" between successive elements of original set.

Comment: Ham Lemon, you should not accept your own answer as the best one by putting a green tick. Noone should decide whether his/her answer is good or not. It should be a decision of other people.

Comment: No @Angelo, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/policy-on-accepting-my-own-answer or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25961/is-it-the-best-to-post-an-answer-to-my-own-question-and-accept-it (but other people can still decide by voting).

Comment: @Angelo, If there is a mistake in my answer, kindly let me know. Since the discussion had ended in the chat and no answer was going to be posted, I decided to post my own understanding and explanation of the question and had previously verified it with people (outside of stack exchange). That is why I verified my own answer.

Comment: @HamLemon, if you want me to talk about some mistakes in you answer, I can tell you that the following sentence you wrote is not correct: “Let us take a rational number $x$ and let us say the immediate next rational number of $x$ is $x+y$”. In fact there does not exist the immediate next rational number, because between two rational numbers there are infinite rational numbers.

Comment: @HamLemon, also the sentence “Thus we essentially squeezed two rational numbers in $[0,1]$ into the interval $[1/2,1]$ by reducing the distance between them” is not the right explanation about why there exists a bijection from $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ to $[1/2,1]\cap\Bbb Q$. Actually the two sets have the same infinite cardinality despite the fact that the second set is a proper subset of the first one.

Comment: @HamLemon, your final conclusion “*we can conclude that any algebraic/geometric manipulation to make number of elements (infinite) in one set equal to that in another set of intuitively larger (or smaller) length, we unintentially/intentionally squeeze (or eleongate) the distances between successive elements of original set*” is not the right interpretation about why an infinite set has the same cardinality than some proper subset of it.

Comment: @HamLemon, if your final conclusion were correct, a infinite set $A$ would have the same cardinality than some proper subset $B$ of $A$ only in the case that it is possible to define the distance between two elements of $A$. Actually there exists a bijection from every infinite set $A$ to some proper subset $B$ of $A$ even though it is not possible to define the concept of distance.

Comment: @HamLemon, I also want you know that I have not downvoted your answer, so it means that someone else does not think it is correct what you wrote. Moreover noone has upvoted your answer. So far you are the only person who considers your own answer to be very good (in fact you put a green tick on it).

Comment: @Angelo I did not say you had downvoted my answer, but you commented that I should not be approving my own answer. All I am trying to say is I have confirmed my logic with several people outside of this site and I posted an answer because 1) there was no other answer, 2) it seemed good enough to provide a qualitative approach to the question

Comment: Also, "take the immediate next rational number from x to be x+y" is not incorrect because I did not say anything about y nor did I assert that the immediate next number of x is rational. All I am trying to convey is that if the rational number closest to x is x+y (numerically we cannot say what will be closest to ½ but we can assume it to be ½ + y WLOG) then I performed so and so calculations which are perfectly fine. It should not matter that we know y or not, the arithmetic calculations are the same

Comment: Also, I put distance in quotation marks in my answer to signify that I was not literally talking about distance between two numbers. I obviously know there is nothing such as distance between two successive numbers, but I was giving a qualitative analysis of a set with infinite elements. I do know the mathematical reasoning of why a set with infinite cardinality has a subset of the same cardinality but I was trying to make it more intuitive by giving various logical explanations of all the examples stated in the answer

Comment: What I am trying to say in my last statement is that (taking the numbers example), if we plot the numbers on a number line, then the length between two numbers in [0,1] will be greater than the corresponding numbers in [½,1] because of our algebraic manipulation and so even though intuitively [0,1] has more numbers than [½,1], the cardinality of both sets appears the same. Or as I said in the geometric example, the distance between the points decreases so we can "fit" all points from line BR (which intuitively should be more) into AR (or find a corresponding point in AR for every point in BR)

Comment: I do not think that this logic is wrong, and the mathematics involved in my post is very basic which is for all beginners to provide a more intuitive approach to sets having "same" infinite cardinality but appears to be different. I was addressing my own question in the post "why does it "look" like the number of rational numbers in [0,1] = number of rational numbers in [½,1] by using this mathematical manipulation even though [0,1] has more than [½,1]?". The other answer to this would simply be that $\frac{\infty}{2} = \infty$ only ....

Comment: .....but by introducing "distance" (which is the root cause of this "paradox"), I was able to address the intuitive challenge in understanding this which I previously had faced

Comment: Why are you the only person who has accepted your answer? Why there is not any person who upvoted your answer? And why did someone (not me) downvote your answer? Are you sure there exists the rational number closest to $x$? What do you mean when you write “distance”? It is not clear at all.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "are you sure there exists a rational number closest to x?" I explained it earlier too, out of all rational numbers there has to be a rational number which is closest to x and we call it x+y. What is the problem in that. And as I said before "distance" is a qualitative term like I gave the example of the two lines AR and BR, or when you plot the numbers on a number line. I do not  understand how after trying to explain it with so many examples, there seems to be a lack of understanding? Also, why should I care if someone downvoted this answer on stach exchange...

Comment: I said before, I have verified this with qualified professors and wanted to give a non mathematical reasoning to infinite cardinality sets and I have said before, this proof is just to give someone who is a beginner like me an intuitive explanation to this rather confusing theory and I thought it would be alright to post my answer below my own question and verify it myself. Then if someone finds it wrong, I can't help with that