# Real analysis, topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

*"If a set is equivalent to one of its proper subset then it is infinite set"*

I was wondering why can't it be countably infinite? Since $\mathbb{Z} \sim \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{Z}+ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}+ \sim \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to its proper subset but Z is countably infinite.. Please correct me where I am getting it wrong

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Countably infinite is infinite.

Comment: Hello, you seem to have confused the title field for the tags field. You should think about making your title informative about the question you are asking. I've taken the liberty of providing a better title. Please do something similar in the future.

Comment: It always is true, assuming the axiom of choice, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525466/if-a-is-infinite-does-there-have-to-exist-a-subset-of-a-that-is-equivalent-to-a): A set is infinite if it is equivalent to one of its subsets.

Answer (score 4):

There is no contradiction. Countable infinity is just a special kind of infinity.

Comment: Thank you .got it!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you. This will gain you (and me as well) rep, which enables perks on the site.